# What is the T and the I in dispatcher language?

Tags: airline-operations, flight-planning, dispatch

From [October 2019 ASRS CALLBACK](https://asrs.arc.nasa.gov/publications/callback/cb_477.html), a captain told a story when the dispatcher

> told me, “All the ‘T’s had been crossed, and all the ‘I’s had been dotted: everything has been done the right way, routine... etc.”

What is the ‘T’ and the ‘I’ mean in this sentence? What is their significance?

Comment: [It's referencing an idiom.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dot_the_i%27s_and_cross_the_t%27s) Or are you asking about what the dispatcher would have actually done?

Comment: Hah it is English word, not aviation specific. Yes this is the answer I want. So the dispatcher means he alr do every thing needed for the flight. Thx a lot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would probably be better suited for [English](http://english.stackexchange.com), as it's a phrase that really has nothing to do specifically with aviation. However...

Having `dotted your "I"s and crossed your "T's` [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/dot-the-i-s-and-cross-the-t-s) that you've paid attention to all the details, that you've finished everything that needs to be done, the job is complete.

An uncrossed "T" could be a capital "I" or a lower-case "L". An undotted "I" could be a lower-case "R" or "E". These are especially true of hand-written, cursive letters. So crossing your "T" ensures clarity and completes the job.

When the dispatcher said this to the captain, he was telling him that he'd gone over all the details and the job was done.